# How to use cookie to save selected value for the all the pages? (Eg. currency, language)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's say site has multiple pages and multiple contents. Some content is displayed on website, and we use drop down to change the content and links. I created select dropdown to select currency and language but whenever we move from page1.php to page2.php. The values of those dropdown gets changed. So whenever a visitor changes the dropdown from any page. It should remain same when he visits other pages.

For eg. a visitor who selects french and EUR so it should remain same on all the pages. He can update the  dropdown from any page on whole website.

Similar to how many websites have currency selection option in their webpages, it remains same throughout the website and we can change it at any page and then that currency becomes the default for all the pages.

I am thinking to use cookies. Please advise how this can be done.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var saveclass = null;

function onChangeHandler() {
  const lang = document.querySelector('#lang').value;
  const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;
  var strLink = "https://example.com/index.php?lang="+lang+"&currency="+currency;
  document.querySelector('#theButton').setAttribute('href', strLink);

}

onChangeHandler();

document.querySelector('#lang').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
document.querySelector('#currency').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="price.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <select name="" id="lang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="currency">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
  </select>

  <a href="" id="theButton">Click</a>
  
    <a href="file2.php">Click</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions storage of javascript, when loading each page you check if a value was already saved, if so you use it. As session storage is a key value object, you can save the language,the currency and other stuff you need. If you want data to never expire then use local storage which is used in the same way.

Session storage 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Local storage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Example

```
$(document).ready(()=>{ 
//get data from the session storage when the page is loaded
 const selectedValue = sessionStorage.getItem('lang');
  //if one value was saved then use it, if not put your default value 
  $("#lang").val(selectedValue !== undefined ? selectedValue:'Default value');
  //when the selected option is changed, it puts the new value in the sessionStorage
  $( "#lang" ).change(function() {
            sessionStorage.setItem('lang', this.value);
        })
})
```

Comment: I understand that but how the same cookie will be used on next page and it will change the dropdown value automatically. I am not  able to figure out this. I am sorry but I have just started coding.

Comment: With the session or local storage you don't use a cookie. The value is saved in the navigator so there will be present in the other pages. Then when you arrive in the next page, you will have to get the saved value and modify the dropdown with that value

Comment: Can you refer me to some working example where a value of drop down is taken to next page and used there? I tried ad scratched my brain for whole day and I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: I just added an example in my first answer